# VBscript to run a bat file with elevated privileges

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, sccm

Here is my bat file

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate" /v SusClientId /f
REG DELETE "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate" /v SusClientIdValidation /f
C:\Windows\System32\wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /detectnow
C:\Windows\System32\wuauclt.exe /reportnow
```

The bat file doesn't work unless it's run inside an "Administrator Command Prompt"

My question is how can I use a VBScript wrapper to run the bat file as an Admin?

I was trying to run this bat file with SCCM but it didn't work. We used a support incident ticket with Microsoft to find out that we need a VBScript wrapper to launch the bat file as an Admin.

Comment: You tagged this with SCCM. Typically SCCM commands are run as SYSTEM which is already an elevated admin.

Comment: I added more info to this.

Comment: "need a VBScript wrapper to launch the bat file as an Admin"  nonsense

Comment: We use psexec to launch a cmd.exe session as SYSTEM.  Then run your .bat files.  If it works there, it should work in SCCM.  There really isn't enough detail in your question to go beyond that.  SCCM logs and what not.  Even then it's more ServerFault then StackOverflow.

Comment: I was really hoping for a VBScript solution. We aren't allowed to use psexec tools (Policy). SCCM logs aren't available to anyone. I have to create the script (bat files) then rely on the information provided by the SCCM Admin about error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the runas verb

```
HelpMsg = vbcrlf & "  ShVerb" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  David Candy 2014" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf & "    ShVerb <filename> [verb]" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator" & vbcrlf & "  of the menu work when used this way" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf 
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running" & vbcrlf & "  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying" & vbcrlf & "  a message box." 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag = WScript.Arguments 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Ag.count = 0 then 
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - No file specified"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    Else If Ag.count = 1 then 
        If LCase(Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/")) = "/h" or Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/") = "/?" then 
            wscript.echo HelpMsg 
            wscript.quit
        End If
    ElseIf Ag.count > 2 then 
        wscript.echo vbcrlf & "  ShVerb - To many parameters" & vbcrlf & "  Use quotes around filenames and verbs containing spaces"  & vbcrlf
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    If fso.DriveExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
'       Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.self
        msgbox ag(0)
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    ElseIf fso.fileExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    Else
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - " & Ag(0) & " not found"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    Set objVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs

    'If only one argument list verbs for that item

    If Ag.count = 1 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If len(cmd) <> 0 then CmdList = CmdList & vbcrlf & replace(cmd.name, "&", "") 
        Next
        wscript.echo mid(CmdList, 2)

    'If two arguments do verbs for that item

    ElseIf Ag.count = 2 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If lcase(replace(cmd, "&", "")) = LCase(Ag(1)) then 
                wscript.echo Cmd.doit 
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    'Properties is special cased. Script has to stay running for Properties dialog to show.
        If Lcase(Ag(1)) = "properties" then
            WSHShell.AppActivate(ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties")
            msgbox "This message box has to stay open to keep the " & ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties dialog open."
        End If  
    End If
End If
```